# Change the style of the built in login button of facebook HTML & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, api

I want to edit my facebook button, but the problem is if i'm applying the style in the fb:login-button, there was a change but it's .5 second only and i tried to put a button inside of the fb:login-button but the problem is the style didn't work, please help me out of this problem.

Here's my code

```
<script>
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.
// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
// for FB.getLoginStatus().
if (response.status === 'connected') {
// Logged into your app and Facebook.
testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
// The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Login with Facebook ';
} else {
// The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
// they are logged into this app or not.
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Login with Facebook ';
}
}
// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button. See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
});
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : '2375346026053474',
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
// the session
xfbml : true, // parse social plugins on this page
version : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
});
// Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
// FB.getLoginStatus(). This function gets the state of the
// person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
// the callback you provide. They can be:
//
// 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
// 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
// 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
// your app or not.
//
// These three cases are handled in the callback function.

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
});
};
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful. See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response) {
console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '<p>Welcome '+response.name+'! <a href=login.php?name='+ response.name.replace(" ", "_") +'&email='+ response.email +'>Continue with facebook login</a></p>'



});
}

</script>
```

and here's the button code:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    LOGIN BUTTON
</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: You can not change the login button provided by Facebook, beyond what the documented configuration options allow for. The button is rendered as an iframe, and since its content is from a different origin, you have zero access to it using JS or CSS. You can use your own custom element, and have it call `FB.login` on click though, then you have full control over how it looks.

Comment: hi 04FS? can you give me any ide to do this? Please, i'm currenly a beginner and willing to learn about web devlopment. thank you so much! @04FS

Comment: Start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#logindialog